# Smart app banner

Tags: jquery, html, meta-tags

I'm trying to implement a smart app banner on my company website but it seems that they are not customizable.
First, the banner shows always on top of the page. Then, I can't set how much time will it be visible after page load. And the thing that really bothers me is the position. Is it possible to use it on the bottom of the site?

Got my info here:

http://david-smith.org/blog/2012/09/20/implementing-smart-app-banners/

For implementation I'm just using this on the :

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=311507490"/>
```

Is there a way to customize these meta tags?

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a fully customizable, Android or iOS, smart app banner that lets you control the position in addition to closing it after any arbitrary time. https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Smart-App-Banner-Deep-Linking-Web-SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://functionsource.com/post/smart-app-banners), [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html), [this](http://www.snackoclock.net/2012/09/implementing-smart-app-banners-in-ios6/) and [this](http://chooseplugin.com/plugin-info/smart-app-banner/)  you cannot change the position of the smart app banner.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jquery plugin that provides this functionality not only for older ios versions but also for android: http://jasny.github.com/jquery.smartbanner/#

You'd need to customize it to never let the native functionality take over, but then you can controll where and how it appears.