# not able to make the smart app banner for android show

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

I am trying to put a smart banner for android devices.
I have followed following links already, have tried the "smartbanner" plugin as well, but nothing works.
reference of links followed:
[stack question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689771/smart-app-banner)
[Creating an android smart app banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168706/creating-an-android-smart-app-banner)

I have coded following the link below then:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/app-install-banners-native/

using the below code it worked only one time and even after clearing cache and history it is not coming again.
code for manifest.json:

```
{ 
 "short_name": "Coach",
 "name": "Coach",
 "icons": [
 {
  "src": "/clientlibs/base/sw/resources/icon192x192.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "36x36"
},
{
  "src": "/clientlibs/base/sw/resources/icon192x192.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "48x48"
},
{
  "src": "/clientlibs/base/sw/resources/icon192x192.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "192x192"
},
{
  "src": "/clientlibs/base/sw/resources/icon192x192.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "512x512"
}
],
"prefer_related_applications": true,
"related_applications": [
{
  "platform": "play",
  "id": "com.baa.app_name",
  "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details? 
 id=com.baa.app_name&hl=en_GB&gl=US&pli=1" 
}
],
"start_url": "./", 
"display": "standalone"
}
```

code for head tag:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<script> 
    let deferredPrompt;
    window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
      e.preventDefault();
      // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
      deferredPrompt = e;
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
        console.log('beforeinstallprompt Event fired!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
      });
    });
</script>
<link
  rel="manifest"
  href="/clientlibs/core-base/sw/resources/manifest.json"
/>
</head>
```